# Force evaluation of multiple variables using vector of character

Tags: r

Is there a way to force the evaluation of multiple variables using a character vector?

for example:

```
x = 1
y = 2
```

instead of doing this:

```
force( x )
force( y )
```

do something like this:

```
force( ls() )
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you are hoping to use such functionality?

Comment: Carl - Not much =)  I took the lazy-man approach and posted here.

Comment: Ricardo - Its a bit complicated.  I have a situation where some code is running in parallel (package 'parallel' and 'foreach') but instead of passing evaluated values, the parallel code is passing a promise.  This would be ok if the promise can be resolved, but the new parallel processes do not have access to the same environments that the promise does.  So I need to force evaluation before running my task in parallel so that the promise is resolved and the values are passed, not the promises.  Like I said...complicated! =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replacing `force()` with `eval(as.symbol())` will do the trick:

```
## Modified from an example in ?force (h.t. @flodel)
g <- function(x,y) {
    lapply(ls(), function(X) eval(as.symbol(X))) 
    function() x+y 
}
lg <- vector("list", 4)
for (i in 1:2) for (j in 1:2) lg[[i+j-1]] <- g(i,j)
lg[[1]]()
# [1] 2
```

This works because, as noted in `?force`:

> [force] is semantic sugar: just evaluating the symbol will do the
>        same thing

Comment: sweet!! I wrapped with invisible() to hide output.

Comment: Nicely done.  Came back to post nearly the same thing after trying some things out myself off and on since the original post -- and here you are with a great answer already.